How to get the "view" when it comes to OnClickListener for Android Studios?
Very basic Android Studio question:
How do I activate that Toast?

Normally, if I type in anything in Android Studio, I get a list of code I can Alt+Enter on / click on and it implements it. How do I implement that in the attached picture? so it looks like this:

I clicked the buttons that normally would implement stuff like Alt+Enter but that doesn't seem to be working. How do I get that second image from that first image?
Edit: I found a good example of what i mean: check out this youtube:> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OP0tK5FAMn8 <: at the "15min and 21secont TO 22second mark" you'll see what i mean. after homeboy puts down the code, it 'goes into the second picture.' it plugs in "it:View". BUT WHEN IIIIIIIII DOOOO IIIITTTTT!? i get the "First picture". a toast asking me if i want to plug in the "it view" thing. and im saying: "YES! I WANT THAT!" and im here on stackoverflow asking: "How do i get to that second picture? im not getting that. Im getting to the first picture. Id like the "it:view" that the system plugs in. do i have to click something for that? cause i normally do alt+enter- and that's not working. This is my question"
Second Edit:
Some have suggested i press enter, and then paste the code; or to just press enter, and that it will show up on its. its not. here's the attached image of it not showing up on its own: attaches another image its still missing the "it:view"
My question revolves how to get that "it:View!" on there. the pressing of enter after the brackets is not implementing it on its own. Im sorry for sharing what im sharing but im really thankful for all the help. We are targetting the right question tho
Third Edit & Potential Answer:
Thank you to @Computable for sharing this attaches response of a potential solution using ctrl+space
WHEN I DID @COMPUTABLE 'S RESPONSE of CTRL+Space (Which, btw, i loved. its amazing.) i found myself looking at:> this attached image and i pressed the one with the green arrow (i pressed the one with the green arrow, cause i couldnt find the dot dot dot one that computable mentioned).
Am i clicking on the right one? cause i got this code/image in response:> AND IT LOOKS RIGHT!? But is that my inexperience talking? cause im trying to get "it: View" but this one says, essentially???? the same thing???? Maybe thats my inexperience talking cause "essentially the same thing" and "the same thing" are not "the:> same <:thing" and i dont wanna move on from this saying: "GOOD ENOUGH!" if its not even "the:> same <:thing"
you know?
Fo realsie- yall helping me are beautiful. i just wanna know how to activate that toast to get "it: View" and fr fr: "Ctrl+space" is a beautiful thing to learn- even tho that wasnt what i was going for hahaha
My main question is still:> "how to get the "it:View" found in the second image, from the first image. @Computable 's response, got me to a potential answer. But my inexperience is leading me to ask:> "are those two the same thing?" or would i still have to do something else to get to "it: View"?
Fourth & Final Edit including: WE FOUND THE ANSWER! (& Closing Conclusion of how we got there:)
MY FELLOW STACKOVERFLOWIANS! WE DID IT! WE TURNED IT INTO IT VIEW! LOOK: attaches image THAT'S MY IT VIEW! THAT'S MINE!!! WOOT WOOOOOOOT!!!!!
I would like to thank both: @NguyễnMạnhCường / @Nguyễn Mạnh Cường (idk how to tag you properly but you have a cool *** name & i love you for helping me from across the world like that. i love you Nguyễn Mạnh Cường) for sharing with me that "WHAT IIIIIIII WAS LOOKING AT! Was a "Settings" thang. Cool. Didnt know that. Homebrah told me: "Go to yo settings/editor/inlay hints" then: "Check lambdas" (And y'all are not gonna believe this but: "LAMBDAS!? WAS THE OOOOOOONLY ONE NOT TURNED ON!!!" and good lohd. when i clicked that on? Boomchakalakababywhatsup. We got to our answer. thas' MY, IT VIEW! i didnt know how to properly ask the question. but i knew how to point to it and go: "THAT! HOW DO I GET THAT!? I WANT THAT!" and Nguyễn Mạnh Cường came along and gave not only the answer i was looking for; but also explained that: "it:View" is a "hint" generated by the IDE then told me how to turn it on and off. i didnt know that folks.
i didnt know what to ask but i knew what to point to; and so many of you came and helped me out so wonderfully. and now that i got to my answer im like: "YEP! LOOK AT LIL OL NEWBIE ME ASKING WHERE'S THE "TURN ON HINT BOX" AND NOT KNOWING IT WAS CALLED: "Lambda"" hahahahahahahahah LOVE IT!
SO MANY OF YOU CAME AND HELPED ME! So many of you came and gave me different pieces of advice from:
@NguyễnMạnhCường
@Lule (Who gave the same (but more detailed) advice- but i saw Nguyen's first- and tested theirs out- AND SO THANK YOU! YOU EVEN GAVE DETAILED PICS! YOU A G @LULE !)
@tyczj for being so patient with me and sharing with me solutions on how to get to where im going but my stubborn self was trying to find the hint box without knowing i was asking for the hint box to be turned on hahahahaha
@Computable for teaching me about ctrl+space ! You're a G
And a def "No, Thank You" to the ppl editing my text and removing the american flavor in my language. "Your mother never loved you- and it's because you do stuff like this" <3.
Have a great life everyone! Thank you for helping me out on this adventure and I wish all your dreams come true!!!

Can you explain the difference between the second image and the first image. do you mean the second image has "it:view"?

Yes. How do i get that? how do i get it:view, from the first image? the first image recommends "it:view" and i wanna say: "Yes. lets plug in that recommendation." the second image HAS IT IMPLEMENTED. the first image seems to be asking me: "Do you want to implement this view thang?" and i wanna say: 'yes!' my question is: "how do i click it? i tried double clicking. i tried alt+enter. but its not becoming the second image from the first image. get my question?

At that point in the video, the presenter is "pasting the copied code here" and the result of that is your second picture - where the next lines following are the pasted code.

no no no; its not the paste. i did the copy paste to make sure if it was the paste; it wasnt the paste. But i feel we are getting to what im asking. thats what im asking. how do i get that "it: view" (found in the second image) that shows up from that toast-hint-in the first image. What did the person do (before the paste) to get that? I did the copy paste; it wasnt that.

Ah, it was quick - when typing the setOn and prompted for completion (or use ctrl-space to get the prompt)- be sure to select  the form {..} (..) and once selected hit enter between the {}.  At that point it's your code to implement (or paste if following the video).

I love this @Computable ! so much so i have edited my question to show where that response took me! but now its leading me to a secondary question: "Im not getting: "it: View"" im getting something else ("View.OnClickListener") are those the same thing? like the same same thing? or like same but diff? hahaha i loved what you taught me tho- the ctrl+space and for that i am incredibly thankful to you cause thats going to help a lot as time goes by and i appreciate you wholeheartedly for it =D!

Concluding comment to clean up this post: "TURNS OUT I WAS ASKING "HOW DO YOU TURN ON THE HINT BOX!?" BUT VIA POINT AT "it: View" AND BEING LIKE: "how i get that?"! it's "Settings/Editor/inlay Hints and "Check Lambdas"" with THAT on @Computable you get to the thing that allows: "it: View" to show up! =D! I didnt know how to ask but thank you so much for ctrl+space ! HAVE A BEAUTIFUL LIFE COMPUTABLE!!!

I have to tell you this. "it:View" is a "hint" generated by the IDE.
It helps you understand that in this lambda there is a variable named it, type View. You can even rename this variable by specifying the name as in the following example:
binding.password.setOnClickListener{viewPassword: View -> }

Or
binding.password.setOnClickListener{viewPassword -> }

If you don't specify its name, the IDE will always automatically assume that the variable is named "it".
So, Even if "it:View" is not visible(Maybe some IDE settings turned it off). But you can still use it.
Update:
I found a way to make the IDE always show this hint.
First go to Settings/Editor/inlay Hints. Check Lambdas And click OK.
Now that hint will always be visible and you will see "it:View" as you want.

YAAAAAAAAS! THIS DIIIIID IIIIIIITTTTTTT!!!!! WOOOOT WOOOOOOOOOOT!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THAAAAAANK YOUUUUU!!!!!!! OKAY! so my question was essentially asking: "How do i turn on the hint box?" but i didnt know i was asking that- BUT YOU CAME IN LIKE A SUPERHERO AND BOTH EXPLAINED TO ME WHAT I WAS LOOKING AT AND SHARED WITH ME HOW TO DO IIIIIITTTT!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!! You are loved- appreciated- and i wish you a wonerful Life Nguyễn Mạnh Cường!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

The bracket is the scope of the on click listener which has the view so it always there. There is no difference between the two images you have aside from the brackets being expanded out. The it is of type View and always going to be view in the case. This is a lambda so there is nothing else you need to "implement", this is the callback for the button click. Notice how onClick gives you the view as a parameter? This is exactly the same thing just less verbose
Example:
binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener{
    Log.d("MyActivity", "Button Clicked")
    it.getId() //ID of the view you have in your xml
}

is the same as
binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener{ view ->
    Log.d("MyActivity", "Button Clicked")
    view.getId() 
}

And all are the same as the more verbose way
binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener()){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Button Clicked")
    }
}

Doing it the last way, Android Studio will suggest that you do the other ways anyway

Sorry boss, i don't understand what you're saying. im asking, how do i get the second image, from the first; when the first; shows me that toast. i dont see that response in your explanation boss. sorry.

@Scholah please explain what you mean, the two images are the same thing

no they're not. look closer @tyczj . the 1st image offers a toast. after the 1st curly bracket, there is a toast that says: "I: View.OnClickListener?" & then the 2nd image, has that toast- IMPLEMENTED
The 1st image asks me, "Do i want to plug that in?" & i am saying YES! I DO WANT TO PLUG IN THAT VIEW! aka:> "when its 'plugged in', it LOOKS LIKE, THE 2nd IMAGE.
Thats my question, how do I plug it in from that 1st image, to that 2nd image; from that toast. how do i activate that toast above the bracket; into the bracket; without typing anything in. the equivalent of alt+enter to plug in?

@Scholah and what I am saying is that they are exactly the same thing, hit enter on the closed bracket in the first image and you have the second image like I described in my answer, there is nothing to "plug in"

i mean this with love and respect @tyczj but "it's not doing that." i click enter, on the closed bracket, and its not giving me the second image. it sticks to first image. ive also attached a youtube in the question that shows exactly what im trying to do; and idk how to do that. the enter on the closed bracket is not doing it tho boss. just being real with ya

@Scholah regardless of what shows in the UI you still have the view object, you access the view object with the it key word. This is a basic kotlin idiom and you dont have to do anything to enable it. Please at least try to do what I am suggesting because you will see that you can access anything from the view object

I dig it- i do. im not trying to be difficult- i'm just, as a new person, trying to get the right replication in my learning/testing/building adventure. not necessarily "close enough" but like: "exact." like. i need the "it: View" to show up and it just aint. and if i move forward with what you're typing in. id be moving forward with: "Something that's not exact but should work" and hey thats great but in my inexperience im kinda looking for 'how to get the exact: "it: View"" in this question- if you get what im saying

Concluding comment to clean up this post: "TURNS OUT I WAS ASKING "HOW DO YOU TURN ON THE HINT BOX!?" BUT VIA POINT AT "it: View" AND BEING LIKE: "how i get that?"! it's "Settings/Editor/inlay Hints and "Check Lambdas"" with THAT on WE GOT TO OUR SOLUTION!!!! WOOT WOOOOOT! THANK YOU SO MUCH @tycjz for your patience and alternative ways to get to where i'm going! i have written down notes to write this diff and i'll be testing it out in future builds! You are loved & appreciated and i wish you a wonderful day & life!

Position your caret next to the first curly bracket {, then press Alt+Enter/Option+Enter, this will open up this menu, select the "Enable option 'Implicit receivers and parameters' for 'Lambdas' inlay hints".


i'm not getting that option. when i click alt+enter- i get: (A) 'convert to multi-line lambda' (B) surround with witched (C) convert to anonymos function) (D) enable a traling comma by default in the formatter) (E) move lambda argument into parathenses) (F) specify explicit lambda signature. thanks for trying.

Then go to Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints.
Expand the option "Lambda", then "Kotlin" finally check the box for
"Implicit receivers and parameters".

YES! YOU ARE RIGHT @Lule I did it through the "Settings:> Editor:> Inlay Hints" & checked off "Lambda" AND IT DID IT! IT GAVE ME "it: View"! WOOOT WOOOOOT!!! AND YOU EVEN ATTACHED A PICTURE FOR A SHORTCUT FEATURE ON HOW TO RECOGNIZE IT! YOU ARE AWESOME LULE! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP!!!
